# Sum specified elements of sub-lists

Tags: r

## The idea:

Suppose I have a lists with two vectors. Then, I would like to take the first element of the first vector and divide it by the sum of it and the first element of the second vector of the list. Then do that for all elements of the first list. After that, do the same thing but with the second vector of the list.

## The code of the lists:

```
tau1 <- list(c(0.43742669 , 0.64024429,  0.39660069,  0.11849773), c(0.5060767, 0.4857891, 0.4553237, 0.5045598))
```

## My worked code for only two vectors.

```
 Tau1 <- vector('list', 2)
for(i in seq_along(tau1)){
  for(j in 1:length(tau1[[1]])){
    Tau1[[i]][[j]] <- tau1[[i]][[j]] / Reduce('+', tau1[[1]][[j]], tau1[[2]][[j]])

  }

}
```

## Example:

First element of the list:

```
TT1 <- tau1[[1]][[1]]/(tau1[[1]][[1]]+tau1[[2]][[1]])
 [1] 0.4636196
```

Then for the second element of the list:

```
 TT2 <- tau1[[2]][[1]]/(tau1[[1]][[1]]+tau1[[2]][[1]])
   [1] 0.5363804
```

## The problem:

I would like to do that for arbitrary number of vectors. For example,

`Reduce('+', tau1[[1]][[j]], tau1[[2]][[j]], tau1[[3]][[j]], tau1[[4]][[j]])`

How can I do that automatically? any help, please?

Comment: Use `sum(sapply(tau1, "[[", j))`, for example `Tau1[[i]][[j]] <- tau1[[i]][[j]] / sum(sapply(tau1, "[[", j)) `

Comment: could you please explain what does `1` means here.

Comment: edited my comment, check if it works

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using `Reduce`, then we need to remove the `[[i]]` to get the sum of corresponding `list` elements to get a `vector`.  Then subset by the 'j'th index to divide the 'j'th element of 'tau1[[i]]'

```
Tau1 <- vector('list', 2)
for(i in seq_along(tau1)){
  for(j in seq_along(tau1[[1]])){
    Tau1[[i]][[j]] <- tau1[[i]][[j]] /Reduce(`+`, tau1)[j]
      }

   }
```

---

Regarding the error mentioned in the comments, it can happen if there are non-numeric elements.  The OP mentioned about `NULL` elements, but NULL occurs as a single element in a `list`.  So, there is a possibility of character `"NULL"`.  For e.g.

```
tau1 <- list(c(0.43742669 , 0.64024429,  "NULL",  0.11849773), 
        c(0.5060767, 0.4857891, 0.4553237, 0.5045598))
```

Upon running the code above

> Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @Alice Do you have any non-numeric elements in your original list i.e. `5 + "10"
#Error in 5 + "10" : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @Alice Can you show an example so that I can look into

Comment: I will tried to make it so simple since it is very difficult.

Comment: @Alice Is there a possibility that the `list` lengths are different.  The error is very clear that somehow, a non-numeric element is creating trouble

Comment: @Thank you for your comment. All does not work. However, I found `NULL` with my list. I think this is the problem. Are you agree? I will fix and see.

Comment: @Alice Okay, that is the issue.  So, you have NULL elements.  Then the length will not be the same also.  How do you want to fix it?

Comment: @Alice I tried by creating an example `tau1 <- list(c(0.43742669 , 0.64024429,  0.39660069,  0.11849773), c(0.5060767, 0.4857891, 0.4553237, 0.5045598), NULL)`, but it is not giving the error you mentioned.  If we need to remove the NULL elements, then `tau1 <- Filter(Negate(is.null), tau1); Tau1 <- vector('list', 2)`  Only thing to be make sure that is that whether you have character `"NULL"`

Comment: Thank you for your interest and help. I tried to fix it. I hope it works. I do not have `NULL` elements but my second element of the list is `NULL`.

Comment: I saw that there is a problem with my function does not work as expected to generate two list. `tau[[i]][[j]] <- vecWeights[[i]][[j]]*vecCop[[i]][[j]]` the first is ok but for the second element I got this `[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
numeric(0)` I tried to do it by `mapply` which may will fix it but I really do not know who to do so. `i 1:2` and `j 1:10` any help, please? sorry.

Comment: @Alice The reason for `numeric(0)` is `NULL * 5#
numeric(0)`  Could you change the `NULL` value to 0 or something else and try it

Comment: Thanks so much for your all help. I really appreciate them. The error was in my function for dimensions reasons. Since it is not belong here. So, I summit another question showing the problem. Part of it is done and this part is still. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138652/lapply-returns-errorerror-in-funxi-non-numeric-argument-to-binary. Could you please help me with it. I am really so much sorry.

Comment: @Alice Looks like you got some solution for that in that post

Comment: Thanks, No. it is not loop. also, I want it for arbitrary number of list.

Comment: @Alice the `map2(d, y, ~ map2(.x, .y, `*`))` seems to work for arbitrary number of list

Comment: @Alice Also, if the `length` are the same in 'd', then you could also do `relist(unlist(d)*rep(unlist(y), each = length(d[[1]][[1]])), skeleton = d)`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To work with any number of list elements use apply family of functions with `[[`.

To extract `j` element in each sub-list use `sapply(tau1, "[[", j)`. To sum those elements use: `sum(sapply(tau1, "[[", j))`

PS.: Instead of `for(j in 1:length(tau1[[1]]){}` you should have `for(j in 1:length(tau1[[i]]){}` - just in case.

Comment: sorry, does `[[` extract all the element from both elements of list one by one since you use `j`. is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R one-liner:

```
lapply(tau1, "/", do.call(mapply, c(FUN = sum, tau1)))

# [[1]]
# [1] 0.4636196 0.5685838 0.4655351 0.1901875
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.5363804 0.4314162 0.5344649 0.8098125
```

Or alternatively (from @lmo's comment):

```
lapply(tau1, "/", Reduce("+", tau1))
```

Here is a `purrr` equivalent:

```
library(purrr)

tau1 %>% map(`/`, pmap_dbl(., sum))

# [[1]]
# [1] 0.4636196 0.5685838 0.4655351 0.1901875
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.5363804 0.4314162 0.5344649 0.8098125
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your try. I would like to use as simple code as I can.

Comment: A little cleaner base R implementation is `lapply(tau1, "/", Reduce("+", tau1))`.

Comment: @lmo Yes. I guess it depends whether the actual function (instead of `"+"`/`sum`) is binary (like `"+"`, forcing the use of `Reduce`) or "vectorized" already (like `sum`, allowing to operate on the sublists "in parallel"). Edited my answer with your comment. Thanks