# lapply returns error:Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

## The idea:

I have two lists each contains two vectors. I would like to multiply the first element of the first vector by the first vector of the second list. Then take the mean. second problem is with `Reduce` which return the same error.

## Extra explanation:

`Tau` takes the first vector of the first element of the list. Then, divide it by its sum and the first vector of the second element of the list.

That is:

`Tau[[1]][[1]] <-xy[[1]][[1]] / xy[[1]][[1]]+xy[[2]][[1]]`

`Tau[[1]][[2]] <- xy[[1]][[2]] / xy[[1]][[2]]+xy[[2]][[2]]`

Then:

`Tau[[2]][[1]] <- xy[[2]][[1]] / xy[[1]][[1]]+xy[[2]][[1]]`

`Tau[[2]][[2]] <- xy[[2]][[2]] / xy[[1]][[2]]+xy[[2]][[2]]`

Then, `w` takes the mean for each one.

I tried this:

```
Tau <- lapply(seq_along(tau), function(i) {
      lapply(seq_along(tau[[i]]), function(j) {
        tau[[i]][[j]] / Reduce("+", tau)[j]
      })
    })
```

but the same problem.

```
x <- list(rnorm(10, 0, 2), rnorm(10, 0, 3))
z <- list(rnorm(10, 1, 2), rnorm(10, 1, 3))
d <- list(x,z)
y <- list(c(0.5,0.6), c(0.4,0.3))

xy <- vector("list", 2)
    xy[[i]] <-  lapply(y,'*', d)
```

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

This also does not work.

```
w <- Tau <- list()
 for(i in 1:2){
      for(j in 2){
     Tau[[i]] <- xy[[i]][[j]] /Reduce(`+`, tau)[j]
     w[[i]] <- mean(Tau[[i]][[j]])
}
```

## Example:

I would like to multiply the first vector by the first element of the first vector of `y` list (e.g. `0.5`)

```
> d
```

This multiplied by `0.5`

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] -0.44040072 -1.69336471 -0.04573857 -3.74011962  3.30269244 -3.37658068  3.06804389  0.13188553
 [9]  3.71420040 -0.74085067
```

This multiplied by `0.6` (second element)

```
[[1]][[2]]
 [1] -1.6611338 -1.3624477 -1.4476909  0.6665619 -6.3073039 -2.8770249 -0.3958278 -4.6663914  1.1611647
[10]  2.1651238
```

This multiplied by `0.4`

```
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1]  0.65857032  2.25298174  1.42681523  1.88253492  2.39446475 -2.91032026  1.39494374  0.07196944
 [9]  2.17966571 -1.06532219
```

This multiplied by `0.3`

```
[[2]][[2]]
 [1]  2.2861982 -1.3721936  2.3371474  2.8234391  4.2834482  5.7823569  4.7208008  0.7277582 -1.0594293
[10] -1.1606454
```

I would like to use `lapply` but it returns an error . Any help, please?

Comment: You have a nested `d` list, that's why

Comment: You should use `set.seed` to provide a reproducible example and should also include your desired output for the toy example. This will reduce the number of "back and forth" responses and help answerers produce your desired end result much more efficiently.

Comment: @Imo, I could not get the result. it gave me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `d` and `y` are lists of lists (or in the case of `y`, a list of a vector), you can't do it with just one `lapply`. It can be done with two nested `lapply`s:

```
xy <- lapply(seq_along(d), function(i) {
  lapply(seq_along(d[[i]]), function(j) {
    d[[i]][[j]] * y[[i]][[j]]
  })
})
```

Alternatively, you can use `map2` from the purrr package, which iterates over two lists in parallel.

```
library(purrr)
xy <- map2(d, y, ~ map2(.x, .y, `*`))
```

---

To complete your question, you can use a few operations to find the denominator, divide it, then take the mean. This uses functions from the purrr package (like `map2` above).

```
# multiply each item in d by corresponding number in y
xy <- map2(d, y, ~ map2(.x, .y, `*`))

# sum the first item in each list, then second item in each list
denominator <- map(transpose(xy), reduce, `+`)

# divide each item by the denominator
tau <- map(xy, ~ map2(., denominator, `/`))

# take the mean of each vector within each list
w <- map(tau, ~ map(., mean))
```

Comment: Thanks, and then, can I take the mean as I mentioned in my question?

Comment: This part works but the mean does not. Could you please, help me with it.

Comment: @Alice So you want a list of means of length 2, with the mean of both the vectors in the first item of `xy` and the mean of both the vectors in the second item?

Comment: Thanks. I need to use reduce first and then store them in list. After that, for each vector of the list I need to take the mean. So, the problem is with Reduce.

Comment: @Alice Could you edit into your question what the output of `Tau` and `w` should be?

Comment: @Alice A little clearer, but I still don't understand how many items are contained in Tau. Would I be right to say it's a list of length 2, each containing a vector of length 10?

Comment: it is the same as `xy`. it is a list of two elements (length 2) each element contains  two vectors of length 10. I think that what you meant.

Comment: @Alice In that case, what would be the second element of the second list? Would it be `xy[[2]][[2]] / (xy[[1]][[2]]+xy[[2]][[2]])`

Comment: To be much more clear. The `Tau` takes the first vectors of the first element of the list and divide it by its sum with the first vectors of the second element. I will add example.

Comment: @Alice I understand that, but does it also do the same with the second vectors in each list?

Comment: yes. that is true. by the same idea. just turn around. e.g., xy[[2]][[1]] / xy[[1]][[1]]+xy[[2]][[1]].

Comment: @Alice No, I mean the *second vector* in the first list, and the second vector in the second list. You're referring to the first vector in the second list.

Comment: @Alice To put it another way: you said each of the 2 items in tau contains  two vectors. How would you compute the second vector in the first item?

Comment: Yes. you are correct and I am correct as well. So, `Tau` loop for all vectors of the list. first vector of the first list with first vector of the second list. and second vector for the first list with the second vector of the second list. And the same for the second list.

Comment: I will explain all of them in my question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. How about If I have many list. So, here `lapply` is needed. Do you agree?

Comment: I will try it and see. Thank so so much.